# Optimization with a lower value constraint for positive solutions

Tags: performance, r

Let \$D\$ be a \$N\times N\$ positive definite matrix. I am minimizing a quadratic funtion

$$ f(w)=w^T D\ w$$

with respect to the weight vector \$ w=(w_1, w_2, ..., w_N)\$, subject to the following 
constraints:

- \$\displaystyle\sum_n w_n =1\$
- \$w_n\geq 0\$
- \$w_n \geq \theta \$ or \$ w_n = 0 \quad \forall n\$, for some threshold \$\theta>0\$.

The last constraint means that if the optimizer finds a non-zero solution, then it should be at least
as large as a threshold \$\theta\$.

I am using `solve.QP()` from `quadprog` for the optimization and so I have to input
the constraints in the form \$A^T w \geq b\$. The last constraint is problematic, since I don't see any way of writting it in that form.

What I am doing to deal with this, so far, is this:

- Ignore the last constraint and find a solution that satisfies the rest of the constraints
- Set weights under the threshold \$ \theta\$ to zero, manually, afterwards and then divide the removed weight ammount
  equally to the rest of the weights that satisfy the last constraint.

I expect that this gives an approximation for what the optimizer would have found as a solution, if I could include the last constraint from the begining.  Using this solution the value for the function \$ f\$ is close to the initial solution, but of course differs, depending on \$\theta\$.

*I was wondering if there is some way to implement this, by including the last constraint in the optimization somehow.*

**Toy example:**

```
library(quadprog)
library(corpcor) 

#Sample matrix to work with:
set.seed(0)
Dmat <- cov( volcano+15*rnorm(87*61) ); Dmat
is.positive.definite(Dmat)


N  <- ncol(Dmat) 
dvec <- rep(0, N)

#Constraints:
##sum equals 1:
a0 <- rep(1, N) 
b0 <- 1
##everything positive:
a1 <- diag(1, N)
b1 <- rep(0, N)

#combine the constraints:
Amat <- cbind(a0,a1)
bvec <- append(b0,b1)

#Solve:
sol <- solve.QP(Dmat = Dmat, dvec, Amat, bvec, meq = 1)
w   <- zapsmall(sol$solution) ; w

#Manually set weights under a certain threshold to zero
theta <- .01
w[w <  theta] <- 0 ; w 

#scale to sum up to 1:
w <- w/sum(w) 

#Compare function values:
t(sol$solution) %*% Dmat %*% sol$solution/2
t(w)%*%Dmat%*%w/2
```

Comment: The usual way for implementing these constraints is to introduce a `z_n` boolean variable and set two constraints: `theta * z_n <= w_n`  and `w_n <= M * z_n`. Where M (called "big-M") is something arbitrarily large for your problem. In the case when `z_n` is zero, then `w_n` is forced to zero. In the case when `z_n` is `1`, then `theta <= w_n` is what you wanted (and `w_n <= M` is not really a problem because you picked `M` to be large enough that it won't restrain your problem.

Comment: This means you need to introduce a binary (i.e. discrete) variable and let the solver solve for it. I doubt your `solve.QP` allows for that type of variable and you could be looking for a different type of solver: one for MIQP (Mixed-Integer-Quadratic-Programming).